# How can we check data in controller sent by ajax (not in response) in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to send array data from javascript to a view page..But the array isn't getting passed to the view page. The codes are described below:

//array getting passed from this page

```
<input type="button" name="b">
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/' ?>jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
            question_array=[];
            question_array['what is our nationality?']='Bangladeshi';
            question_array['what is our national fish?']='Ilish';
            number=10;
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "admin/test",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {question_array: question_array,number:number},
                success: function(result) {
                    if (result) {
                           window.location="<?php echo base_url().'admin/test_page'; ?>";
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

`

In my controller::

```
public function test()
{
    $question_array = $this->input->post('question_array');
    $number         = $this->input->post('number');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('number', $number);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('question_array', $question_array);

    echo json_encode($number, $question_array);
}
function test_page()
{
    $this->load->view('admin/test_page');
}
```

//The page where I'm sending the array(Question_array not found)

```
$number         = $this->session->flashdata('number');
$question_array = $this->session->flashdata('question_array');
echo $number;
print_r($question_array);
```

Comment: just remove space in the key and convert it to an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Convert array to `object` and remove spaces between array keys, like this :*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
        var question_array = [];
        question_array['what-is-our-nationality'] = 'Bangladeshi';
        question_array['what-is-our-national-fish'] = 'Ilish';
        var number = 10;
        var obj = $.extend({}, question_array);
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo base_url('admin/test'); ?>",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {question_array : obj, number : number},
          success: function(result) {
            if (result)
            {
              window.location="<?php echo base_url().'admin/test_page';?>";
            }
          }
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may better try JSON.stringify to solve this,

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "admin/test",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({question_array: question_array,number:number}),
    success: function(result) {
        if (result){
             window.location="<?php echo base_url().'admin/test_page'; ?>";
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the code below can help you. You need post the string i correct JSON format by using stringify. The server will receive the json and decode it to object.

```
function send(){
var url = "http://localhost/some_url_here";

var data = JSON.stringify({
    Bangladeshi: 'what is our nationality?',
    Ilish: 'what is our national fish?'
});          
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
}).done(function(output){
    alert('output is '+ JSON.stringify(output));
});
```

}

```
function receive() 
{
    $result = '';

    $stream_clean = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->raw_input_stream);
    $request = json_decode($stream_clean);
    $Bangladeshi = $request->Bangladeshi;
    $Ilish = $request->Ilish;
    $result = array("status" => 200, "id" => $Bangladeshi+$Ilish);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```